# How to send MySQL query results to outfile and standard output at the same time?

Tags: mysql, database

I "normally" query MySQL with

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename LIMIT 10;
```

and sometimes instead send the output to a file with

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tablename LIMIT 10 INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/outfile';
```

Is there a way to do both with one query?  I am trying to store a dump file of the query results while still manipulating the output (in PHP).

Comment: Probably not, you'll need to run the query 2 times, or create the dump using PHP if you only want to run it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the query to a variable, then perform your operations.

```
$result = mysql_query('some stuff');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    do stuff;
} else {
    do stuff;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I am looking for an alternative to this  :-)  It doesn't seem there is a built-in MySQL way to do this, at least not that anyone on db.stackexchange or stackoverflow has found, yet.